# Move Python Turtle horizontally without changing heading

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm working on a game in Python-3 that requires moving a Turtle object horizontally (AKA sideways) without changing my heading.
`turtle.goto(x,y)` or `turtle.setx(x) turtle.sety(y)` won't work because I want the object to show up when moving, just like when you do `turtle.fd(distance)`.

Here is the code I have now:

```
import turtle 
turtle.speed('slowest')
turtle.lt(90)
turtle.fd(20)
turtle.rt(90)
```

With this code, the turtle turns, moves forward, and turns back. Is there a way I could move sideways without having to turn?

Thanks a lot!
Any comments will be welcome!

Comment: The turtle moves to that spot with the predefined speed. If no speed specified, it may seem as the turtle jumps. **Before** executing `turtle.setx(a_number)`, execute `turtle.speed('slowest')` and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> turtle.goto(x,y) or turtle.setx(x) turtle.sety(y) won't work because I
>   want the object to show up when moving

Your premise is false -- the turtle will show up when moving with all of these operations:

```
import turtle

turtle.speed('slowest')

turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 100)

turtle.done()
```

This moves the turtle vertically while maintaining a horizontal heading.  It doesn't teleport, it's the same visible motion as a `.forward()`

However, if you have some *other* reason not to use `goto()`, `setx()`, `sety()`, etc. and want to use `forward()`, `backward()` instead, there's a way we can do this.  The turtle cursor has a concept of *tilt*, allowing it to look in one direction while moving in another:

```
import turtle

turtle.speed('slowest')

turtle.tracer(False)  # hide the heading change ...
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.settiltangle(-90)  # ... until we can tilt it
turtle.tracer(True)

turtle.forward(100)

turtle.done()
```

One situation where we might use this is a space invaders style game where the turtle wants to face towards the top of the window but we want to use `forward()` and `backward()` to control its motion side-to-side on the screen:

```
""" Oversimplified Example """

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
turtle.settiltangle(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.showturtle()

screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.forward(10), "Right")
screen.onkey(lambda: turtle.backward(10), "Left")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```